# Is there a way to delete only clicked element when those elements all have the same ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement "delete comment" option when I click on the comment. However, what I have implemented here deletes comment in the order regardless of what I click and I want it to delete one that I am clicking. I tried using for loop so each one gets different ID with number next to it but it got too complicated to track when someone deletes and adds again. I would greatly appreciate any idea!

```
const createComment = () => {
    // userId
    let userId = "userId"
    // getting comment from input
    const comment = textbox.value;
    // element = comment + like button
    const element = document.createElement('p');
    element.id = "individualComment";
    element.setAttribute("style", "width:430px");
    // like 
    const like = document.createElement("input");
    like.id = "like";
    like.src = "img/navHeart.jpeg";
    like.type = "image"
    like.setAttribute("style", "height: 15px; width: 15px");
    like.style.float = 'right';
    // creating element and append it
    element.innerHTML = userId + "  " + comment;
    whereToAdd.appendChild(element);
    element.append(like);
}
```

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'individualComment') {
    const element = document.getElementById('individualComment');
    element.remove();
    }
})
```

Comment: Pls use code snippets!

Comment: There must never be two elements with the same `id` as it invalidates your HTML.

Answer (score 3):

I used `target.parentNode`, please see snippet below.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'individualComment') {
        var target = e.target;
        var parent = target.parentNode;
        var index = [].indexOf.call(parent.children, target);
        parent.children[index].remove();
    }
})
```

```html
<div>
    <p id="individualComment">Comment 1</p>
    <p id="individualComment">Comment 2</p>
    <p id="individualComment">Comment 3</p>
    <p id="individualComment">Comment 4</p>
    <p id="individualComment">Comment 5</p>
    <p id="individualComment">Comment 6</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should remove the non-unique `id`s in your HTML, as it will be invalid otherwise.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann, I agree, though the question asked how to do it with elements having the same id. My solution would work wether the ids are unique or not.

Comment: @LucasRoquilly First of all tell me what do you mean by the ID ?. If all element have same ID's then what is the sense to give the id's to the element .

Comment: @prathameshmungekar by the id I mean the element's id attribute. Sorry i'm new to answering questions here, I thought we had to answer the question which specifically mentioned "when all elements have the same id". I agree id attributes should be unique on the same page.

Comment: @LucasRoquilly No worry. Just give random id to each element while creating it . And use filter around it. It will  works .

Answer (score 1):

`id`s must always be unique on a page. The following shows a solution based on filtering for a common `class`:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains( 'individualComment')) {
    e.target.remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="individualComment">Comment 1</p>
    <p class="individualComment">Comment 2</p>
    <p class="individualComment">Comment 3</p>
    <p class="individualComment">Comment 4</p>
    <p class="individualComment">Comment 5</p>
    <p class="individualComment">Comment 6</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [] // your initial array
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //when you click any element this event listner get called
    //then you check the target element id with the original array element id
    //Use filter method to filter out only those element whose id not equal to the
    //target id . So you will get updated array without target element
    array = array.filter(elem => elem.id !== e.target.id);
})
```